# glClearColor and glClear with GL_RGBA16F?

Tags: opengl-es

Is there any known problem when trying to clear a buffer in openGL when the buffer is in format GL_RGBA16F?

I am attempting to clear a render-to-texture buffer with:

```
glClearColor(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

...but the buffer is being made solid red.  That looks to me like it's only writing the first component, ignores the rest, and moves onto the next pixel.  I'm using GLES3.0.  Is this a bug or is there something special I need to do to clear this entire buffer?

Comment: "*but the buffer is being made solid red.*" How do you know that?

Comment: By rendering it.  My drivers allow me to render a GL_RGBA16F into the framebuffer.

Comment: What do you mean by "your drivers allow" that? Are you using RGBA16F *as* the framebuffer, or are you rendering with it as a bound texture? Because all drivers "allow" the latter. And if it is the latter, are you sure you're reading from it and writing to the framebuffer correctly?

Comment: I mean, I can render to a RGBA16F texture, write floats into it with a shader, SetTexture to that texture, and view my RGB correctly.  If I "clear" it by drawing a huge triangle with a shader that just writes my desired RGB and that works (but obviously I can't set 0 alpha that way).  However, just calling glClear sets only the red component when I specify glClearColor(1,1,1,1).  Which makes me suspect glClear is only writing to the red because of the odd sizing.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to create the framebuffer object? You don't happen to have set the color mask before you clear, have you? Also, you can set 0 alpha when you draw a triangle -- just make sure your blend mode is GL_ONE,GL_ZERO -- that will take 100% of the incoming color/alpha and 0% of the existing color/alpha.